# Decompiled method of Xamarin.iOS application is empty

Tags: xamarin.ios

I tryed to decompile iOS application developed by Xamarin.iOS(Xamarin.Forms), But ILSpy and NET Reflector couldn't decompile all methods correctly. Decompiled method body is prefectly empty.

What can i do for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you will find in a Xamarin Dll inside the app bundle is some metadata required by the runtime. All methods logic won't be there because it has been [AOT'ed](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/) and now the logic lives inside the native binary itself. This is mainly because iOS does not allow dynamic code generation.

You can read more info about how Xamarin works [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_1_-_understanding_the_xamarin_mobile_platform/)

Hope this helps.